# allowing only custom characters using regex

Tags: php, regex, validation

I would like to check if value entered by user **only** either contains *letters, numbers, underscore, forwardslash, dotts, hyphens, and colons* and nothing more.

In short this are the caracter I want to allow. 
Sadly, I can't find exact answer to my problem.

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 _ / - . :
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading a regex tutorial can solve your problem:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\/.:-]+$
```

or

```
^[\w\/.:-]+$
```

Comment: You beat me for 6 seconds, +1.

Comment: @M42: as fast as a lightning

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
preg_match('~^[\w/.:-]+$~', $string);
```

Comment: Does this mean, if any character exists outside the ones mention it will give false ?

Comment: @user2679413: yes,, it does.

Comment: @user2679413, almost. If a line break character is found at the end of the string `$` will allow it. If you do not want to allow an ending whitespace, use `\z` instead of `$`.